# OpenGL - Client-server architecture is relatively slower, isn't it?

Tags: opengl-es

Citing:

> In the client–server model, the commands issued by the client do not
>   necessarily get sent to the server immediately. If the client and
>   server are over a network, it will be very inefficient to send
>   individual commands over the network. Instead, the commands can be
>   buffered on the client side and then issued to the server at a later
>   point in time. As a result, there needs to be a mechanism that lets
>   the client know when the server has completed execution of previously
>   submitted commands.

**OpenGL®ES 2.0 Programming Guide - Aaftab Munshi, Dan Ginsburg, Dave Shreiner**

On the other hand, OpenGL error reporting mechanism (`glGetError`) and other things are implemented so that minimal checks are implemented in order to achieve maximal performance.

Isn't client-server architecture relatively slower then if it was not client-server (stand alone?)? Was it really worth to enable working on different machines using client-server architecture?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While OpenGL has been designed to enable a client-server implementation, a particular implementation is free to implement things in a direct rendering way, i.e. OpenGL calls are executed immediately or with little delay.

However it must be clearly stated that a client-server architecture does not imply a performance penalty. In fact the asynchronous execution model of OpenGL allows implementations so much leeway in the details how operations are carried out, that by internally rearranging the order of operations a better throughput can be achieved than in a straight in-order execution. The only requirement is, that the result of the operations must match those as if things were executed in order. But this is no different to out-of-order execution on modern CPUs.

> On the other hand, OpenGL error reporting mechanism (glGetError) and other things are implemented so that minimal checks are implemented in order to achieve maximal performance.

Well, actually OpenGL requires a lot of internal error checking and validation (this is one of the points addressed by Vulkan, allowing to disable or remove this error checking and validation in release builds). So this statement of yours is not accurate.